# Django - JSON returned from Ajax success to be used in a template

Tags: json, ajax, django

Say I have a Django queryset being displayed in a template with the following view...

```
def objects_view(request):
    user = request.user
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    objects = Product.objects.filter(title = q)
    context = {'user':user,'query':query,'objects':objects}
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

Then an Ajax function in the template.html will be called when a user changes the values of minimum or maximum price like so...

```
$('#apply-price-changes').click(function(){
    var Url = window.location.path; # Calling the same URL so we are POSTing to the same view
    var priceMin = $('#price-min-hidden').val();
    var priceMax = $('#price-max-hidden').val();
    $.ajax({
      async:true,
      method:'POST',
      url:Url,
      data:{
        'minPrice':priceMin,
        'maxPrice':priceMax,
      },
      dataType:'json',
      success:function(data){
        console.log(data) # <- This logs all of the filtered objects (in JSON format) in the console
        # Not sure what I'd write to go here, this bit is the problem
      },
      error:function(error){
        console.log(error)
      }
    })
});
```

So now in my view I include a POST request to get the minimum and maximum price values...

```
def objects_view(request):
    user = request.user
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    objects = Product.objects.filter(title = q)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        minPrice = request.POST.get('minPrice')
        maxPrice = request.POST.get('maxPrice')
        objects = Product.objects.filter(title = q, price__gte = minPrice, price__lte = maxPrice)
        data = serializers.serialize('json',objects)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
    context = {'user':user,'query':query,'objects':objects}
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

Now I'd like to have the result of that data be displayed in the template so that users can see products that only match the filtered queryset, and also be able to do some 'if' statements with that data.

HTML Template example:

```
{% if objects.count > 0 %}
{% for object in objects %}
<h3>{{ object.title }}</h3>
<h4>{{ object.description }}</h4>
<h4>{{ object.price }}</h4>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
No objects to display!
{% endif %}
```

Please let me know if there's any more code I should show. Note that I do not want to print every bit of the information return from JSON, such as the primary key of each object.

Thanks!

Comment: So you're almost done, the fact is that you want to display HTML and you return json. So in order to change that just just use the render function instead of returning the HttpResponse juste like you were returning html, this will build the html like you defined in the HTML Template exemple and you will use jquery to put this html somewhere where you want on the already loaded page.

Comment: @Quentin So would I render a different template in to a div within the current template?

Comment: Also, why the downvote people? I think it's a valid question, if not please let me know why! :)

Comment: Exactly ! I don't know if it's a nice thing to do but it will work.
For the downvote, I don't know, I'm not a StackOverflow expert, I think there is some answers on the web but I do not no if this question deserve a downvote ^^

Comment: @Quentin Just tried to do this, how do you write that in the success function? So basically get the contents of the html file and put them in a div on the page

Comment: Now you deserve the downvote ahah ! Just use 
`let h = $.parseHtml(data)`  
`$("#customDiv").append(h)`

Comment: @Quentin Thank you! Much appreciated :)